# Obter propriedades Css

Tags: javascript, css

Alguém sabe como identificar, usando javascript, somente as propriedades css de uma Classe, por exemplo:

```
.in-text{
   color: red;
   font-weight: 500;
}
```

em html

```
<label class="in-text">Digite um texto</label>
```

Eu tentei este método, `getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.in-text'))`contudo obtenho muitas propriedades e não somente da classe in-text

Comment: Isso é complexo, é mais fácil saber que estilos um dado elemento tem. Podes explicar melhor o que pretendes fazer ou o que precisas saber dessa classe?

Comment: Veja se é isso que precisa, http://jsfiddle.net/HP326/6/, resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element

Comment: @Sergio estava estudando a possibilidade de aplicar as regras de uma classe css de forma inline, numa tag style. Bom saber que isto é muito complexo.

Comment: @abfurlan vlw pelo link, é uma boa base para minhas pesquisas.

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode utilizar o getComputedStyle() que te retorna um object com todos os atributos que foram declarados para o elemento passado.
E utilizando o getPropertyValue() vc passa o nome do atributo css que quer acessar

```
var elemento = document.getElementById("algo");
window.getComputedStyle(elemento, null).getPropertyValue("margin-top")
```

Caso tenha queira saber mais o funcionamento deste, pode ver a documentacao no link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Eu estava querendo descobrir somente as regras de uma classe CSS, neste caso não posso usar o getPropertyValue, pois não possuo as propriedades.